# Web API return Helper Page

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, html-helper

I have a ASP.NET WebPage and like to use the Helper Pages located under App_Code. Now I don't have any clue how to solve this problem: I post data from a html form to my Controller (WebApi 2 HttpPost method) with $.ajax. As a result, I wan't the content of my helper page, whose binding data comes from my controller web api method.

I would like to maintain my form data encapsulated in my model class, because it seems cleaner to me to handle with the data. I also want to access my model in my view.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/{ClassID}/AddUsers")]
public IHttpActionResult AddUsers([FromUri] int ClassID, [FromBody] Models.UserInfo userInfo)
{
    Foo result = new Foo();
    result = doSometStuff(userInfo);

    return ???(HelperPages.FooHelper.Get(result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer my question myself. Web API only returns data, not any view. So I just have to use a mvc controller to do so.